# Класификатор текста для MySql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!Какими средствами можно осуществить  правку текста в базе данных MySql - проверка орфографии, перевод в нижний(верхний) регистр, замена слов и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dbForge Studio for MySQL неплохое решение